# C# strange problem with constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I have IMHO very strange problem with three-argument constructor , When I try to run the program visual studio shows me only one bug: " 'Sort.HeapSort' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments 112 35"  .

```
namespace Sort
{
    class HeapSort
    {
        private int[] A;
        private int heapSize;
        private int min; 
        private int max; 
        Random myRandom = new Random(); 

        HeapSort(int size, int min1, int max1) //this is the three argument constructor.
        {
            heapSize = size - 1;
            min = min1;
            max = max1;
            A = new int[size];
        }    
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 30;
            int min = 0;
            int max = 100;

            HeapSort myHeapSort = new HeapSort(size,min,max); //In this line is the bug
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the constructor public?

Comment: Could you remove useless lines plz :)

Comment: perhaps you should decorate your classes with the proper access modifiers. Public, Private, protected, etc.

Comment: Could you fix the odd formating? (Moglbys naprawiac dziwny format?)

Comment: 8 Answers in a blink of a sloth eye :pLooks like everyone is in the starting block

Answer (score 9):

Your constructor is declared private, since you omitted an access specifier.  Add the `public` keyword prior to the constructor definition.

Comment: You should check the box beneath the update/down vote buttons to accept his answer then instead of editing the title to mark it solved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify your constructor as public, thusly:

```
public HeapSort(int size, int min1, int max1)
```

The compiler allows you to omit the accessibility specifier and defaults to private. Bit of a syntactic sugar gotcha IMO that I wish would be done away with.

So, since you have a private constructor, your client code does not "see" it and the compiler tries to call the public constructor which naturally results in the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor isn't public, it's private (you didn't include any modifiers so it defaults to private) therefore the calling code can't "see" it.

Change:

```
HeapSort(int size, int min1, int max1)
```

To:

```
public HeapSort(int size, int min1, int max1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `public` to your constructor, otherwise it's considered `private`, and therefore inaccessible from within your `Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor with three params has no accessibility modifier on it and so defaults to `private`.

Change the declaration to `public HeapSort(int size, int min1, int max1)` and you'll be good-to-go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing 'public' keyword before constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Make your constructor public !

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is private. It needs to be public.